# How do I use inline templates in MODx Revo?

Tags: authentication, modx

I'm using the Login snippet in MODx Revo and I'm trying to put the template directly in the loginTpl and logoutTpl properties but nothing is being output. Below is my code. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
[[!Login? &tplType=`inline` &loginTpl=`<span>Log In</span>` &logoutTpl=`<span>[[+username]]</span>`]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The placeholders are evaluated before snippet is processed, i.e. before the `@INLINE tpl` is ever used.

> Use chunks;
>   Or non-cacheable placeholder (has not been tested):

```
[[!Login? &tplType=`inline` &loginTpl=`<span>Log In</span>` &logoutTpl=`<span>[[!+username]]</span>`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It fully works, check to see if login component is installed (it is not installed by default).

Comment: The Login snippet is installed but I think now the problem is elsewhere. My site stops loading when I log out of the web context.